# React Native Firebase Dynamic Links

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using react native firebase dynamic links, after completing my setup, i tried to use it, but i faced this error .

APP ERR Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed natively on your iOS project by calling firebase.dynamicLinks().
Ensure you have either linked the module or added it to your projects Podfile.

I tried pod install but still have the error